# Pandas - Calculate the number of customers between startdate and enddate

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to calculate how many customers there were at each time of month in the past year. My dataframe contains customer ID, start-date (where customer started being customer) and end-date (where customer ended being customer):

```
Customer_ID     StartDate    EndDate
1               01/01/2019    NAT
2               25/10/2017    01/06/2020
2               13/06/2012    15/07/2015
2               20/12/2015    03/01/2016
2               25/03/2016    14/06/2017
3               05/06/2018    05/06/2019
3               12/12/2019    NAT
```

The result I would like; is counting the number of customers that were "active" per month-year combination:

```
MONTH YEAR  NUMB_CUSTOMERS
01    2013  1
02    2013  1
03    2013  1
04    2013  1
...
01    2019  2
...
09    2020  2
```

I would like to avoid for-loops as that takes too much long (I have a table of over 100 000 rows).

Has anyone an idea to do this neat and quickly?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you explain the result in more detail? how the number of customers is 1 for a particular month and year?

Comment: @Shrirang: For example, January 2013:  If you check for all the different customer id's, you can see only one customer (Customer ID 2) has an entry where January 2013 falls between start_date and end_date (13/06/2012 - 15/07/2015). The other customers were not 'active' already in january 2013. Therefore, the numb_customers for January 2013 is 1.

Answer (score 0):

First, read data and make it digestible for program

```py
import pandas as pd
import datetime

df = pd.read_csv("table.csv") 
func = lambda x: x.split('/', maxsplit=1)[1]

df["StartDate"] = df["StartDate"].apply(func)

mask = df["EndDate"] != "NAT"
df.loc[mask, "EndDate"] = df.loc[mask, "EndDate"].apply(func)
```

Then, count changes in amount of clients (you basically get a derivative of your data)

```py
customers_gained = df[["Customer_ID", "StartDate"]].groupby("StartDate").agg("count")
customers_lost = df[["Customer_ID", "EndDate"]].groupby("EndDate").agg("count")
customers_lost.drop("NAT",inplace=True)
```

make a grouper for all changes in amount of clients

```py
def make_time_table(start, end):
    start_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(start, "%d/%m/%Y")
    end_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(end, "%d/%m/%Y")
    data_range = pd.date_range(start_date, end_date, freq="M")
    string_range = [el.strftime("%m/%Y") for el in data_range]
    ser = pd.Series([0]*data_range.size, index=string_range)
    return ser
```

Next introduce change into time_table and "integrate" by accumulation

```py
time_table = make_time_table("01/01/2012", "01/12/2020")
time_table[customers_gained.index] = customers_gained["Customer_ID"]
time_table[customers_lost.index] -= customers_lost["Customer_ID"]
result = time_table.cumsum()
print(result)
```

Outputs:

```
01/2012    0
02/2012    0
03/2012    0
04/2012    0
05/2012    0
06/2012    1
07/2012    1
...
10/2019    2
11/2019    2
12/2019    3
01/2020    3
02/2020    3
03/2020    3
04/2020    3
05/2020    3
06/2020    2
07/2020    2
08/2020    2
09/2020    2
10/2020    2
11/2020    2
dtype: int64
```

table.csv

```
Customer_ID,StartDate,EndDate
1,01/01/2019,NAT
2,25/10/2017,01/06/2020
2,13/06/2012,15/07/2015
2,20/12/2015,03/01/2016
2,25/03/2016,14/06/2017
3,25/03/2016,05/06/2019
3,12/12/2019,NAT
```